# get product list using soap api magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Soap Api and want to get product list whose stock is not 0, meaning there is at least 1 inventory(Stock) of the product in magento.
I am using this type of code but it is not working.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'apiUser', 'apiKey' => 'apiKey')); 

$result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productIds' => array(1,2)));   
var_dump($result->result);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric,

Now i am getting this error-                                                                                'Error on line 4 in /home/xxx/xxx.php
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.com/api/soap/?WSDL' : Premature end of data in tag html line 2 '                                                                                                   Please can you help                                                                         thanks

Comment: please anybody can help me ?

Comment: please anybody can help me ?   I am searching since Monday    Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below, it worked for me:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://yourstore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUserName', 'apiKey');
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
var_dump($result);
```

If this did not work for you try to replace the url with the following (add "index.php") http://yourstore.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

### Hope this solves your problem!

Try adding the following lines before the code to enable error logging to see what the error is, seeing a blank screen might be because there is an error but you dont see it:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Can you also access this URL "yourstore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" or this "yourstore.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" directly in your browser and let me know what you see? you should be able to see an XML document, if there is a setting issue, you will see something like "Invalid service adapter" or somekind of an error message.

Comment: Hello Laith, thanks for reply                                                                               I tried this code but it show me blank page  even i print result still it show blank page.                                                                                                  Any other solution ?

Comment: Hello Laith, Thanks for your help. My issue has been solved. I added WWW after http:// mean    `$proxy = new SoapClient('http://yourstore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');` to `$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.yourstore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');`

Answer (score 0):

use v1 api

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$proxy->call($session, 'catalog_product.info',array(1,2));//productIds
```